# Properties hierarchy in spring boot project with dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have common project whith spring configuration class

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource(locations = {"classpath*:spring/spring-test-context.xml"})
public class CommonConfiguration{
}
```

In this *spring-test-context.xml* there are some beans which requires injection of values from properties file.

I use this common library in several projects but these properties are not used in all projects.

So I put them with null value in application.properties file in this common library but they are not visible from there in given projects so I need to add null values in application.properties file in each project which have dependency to common library.

I'd like to have this properties with deafult values in common library and to be overwritten with specific values in project where they are needed ?

How to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve your goal providing the PropertySource from the common library application.properties. Maybe rename it to spring-test-context.properties just to make sure there is no confusion with the standard properties file:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:spring-test-context.properties")
@ImportResource(locations = {"classpath*:spring/spring-test-context.xml"})
public class CommonConfiguration{
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was solution which I needed